# Console.Write shortcut in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

Is there a shortcut to `Console.Write` in Visual Studio 2022?

I find myself using `Console.Write` more than `Console.WriteLine`, and at the moment, I just use the <kbd>cw+tab</kbd> shortcut to write `Console.WriteLine` and then go back and erase.

Comment: You could look into [code snippets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-snippets?view=vs-2022)

Comment: Or maybe a [Macro Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.MacrosforVisualStudio)?

Comment: In Visual Studio, you can create your own code snippets or modify existing ones to suit your preferences. As Ali Kh pointed out, you can mark his answer so it helps more people. If you still have any questions, please feel free to discuss them with us.

Answer (score 3):

Visual studio already has `cw` code snippet for `Console.Writeline` statement.

but if you often use `Console.Write` instead of `Console.Writeline` you can create new code snippet.

From the menu bar, select Tools > Code snippet manager and then select CSharp for language and then select visual C# from folders you can see and then you can add some code snippet.

you can use below article to create your own code snippet for  `Console.Write` statement:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2022